# In how many ways can we select $5$ children from this group so that Mary and Jane are always in the selection?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, word-problem

In a group of $10$ children no two kids have the same name. We know that Mary and Jane are among these children. In how many ways can we select $5$ children from this group so that Mary and Jane are always in the selection?

So I started by looking at all the possible outcomes

$$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}  \implies  \frac{10!}{5!(10-5)!} = 6048$$

from here I get stuck and I don't know how to proceed. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: **Hint** 

If Mary and Jane are guaranteed in the group, it's the last $3$ kids that need picked from the remaining $8$ that make unique groups.

Comment: So fix two children, then we need to select three more from the remaining 8. SO the answer should be $\binom{8}{3}=56$

Comment: You made a computational error.  $$\binom{10}{5} = \frac{10!}{5!(10 - 5)!} = \frac{10!}{5!5!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5!}{5! \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 252$$

Comment: Also, welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If Mary and Jane are always in the selection, then $3$ more children have to be selected from the remaining $8$ children.  Number of ways of selecting $3$ children from $8$ children is

$$= \frac{8!}{(8-3)! \cdot 3!} = 56$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.